# how to filter laravel eloquent results by relation ship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models `TeamleaderCompany` which : has many `TeamleaderCompanyTag`

TeamleaderCompany

```
public function teamleaderCompanyTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TeamleaderCompanyTag');
}
```

TeamleaderCompanyTag

```
public function teamleaderCompany()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TeamleaderCompany::class);
}
```

when  I `TeamleaderCompany::all()` I have this results :

```
(...)
      "teamleader_company_tags": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "tag": "hot lead",
          "teamleader_company_id": 3,
          "created_at": "2019-09-03 09:23:51",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-03 09:23:51"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "tag": "reseller",
          "teamleader_company_id": 3,
          "created_at": "2019-09-03 09:23:51",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-03 09:23:51"
        }
      ]
(...)
```

What I'm trying to do is to show `TeamleaderCompany` results where `teamleaderCompanyTags` has only one `tag` which is `'reseller'` (if there is another tag except 'reseller' don't show)

```
$companies->whereHas(
    'teamleaderCompanyTags',
    function ($query) use ($condition) {
        $query->where('tag',
            (...)
        );
    }
);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two conditions.

- it need to have the "reseller" tag
- it's the only tag that it has

```php
TeamleaderCompany::whereHas('teamleaderCompanyTags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('tag', 'reseller');
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('teamleaderCompanyTags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('tag', '!=', 'reseller');
    })
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```php
TeamleaderCompany::has('teamleaderCompanyTags', '=', 1)     // companies that have only one tag
    ->whereHas('teamleaderCompanyTags', function ($query) { // companies that have `reseller` tag
        $query->where('tag', 'reseller');
    })
    ->get()
```

Comment: thanks , but this returns 'teamleaderCompanyTags' having "reseller" event if there is other Tags what i'm looking for is only "reseller" not other tags .

Comment: @MostafaAbdellaoui you mean companies that have only one tag and that tag is 'reseller' right? check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
TeamleaderCompany::with('teamleaderCompanyTags:id,tag')
->whereHas('teamleaderCompanyTags',function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query){
                        $query->where('tag', "reseller");
                    })->get();
```